# My ETH Wallet was Hacked but I changed the login details

Tags: ether

If someone has hack your wallet before and they stole eth and you change your  details but not the address. Can they still hack your eth even if they only have the eth address?

Comment: You can't "change" details, the only thing you could do is change the password used to encrypt your key. If they have your private key then there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

To hack a wallet, they have to have access to either your:

- A) `Private key`
- B) Any device that has your `private key` stored

You must assume they HAVE the `private key`, as you don't know for 100% that the attacker did or did NOT copy your `private key`.

Once a `private key` has been obtained, the attacker will always have full & unrestricted access to that wallet account.

Time to do a security check on all your devices and create a new wallet account(s).

Answer (score 0):

If your address has been hacked before, this means someone has access to your private key. Changing details on your wallet, such as the password used to decrypt your private key, will not prevent the hacker from robbing you again. So yes, they can hack you again if you send money back to that address.